# 'Could not open the ID file' when using win32com.client in python

Tags: python, lotus, win32com, userid

I have an issue connecting to Lotus Notes from Python using win32com.client.

I am using the following code:

```
import win32com.client
import csv # imports the csv module
import sys # imports the sys module
import re

notesServer = "AALMBX01/Server/..."
notesPass = "PASS"

#Connect to notes database on server
notesSession = win32com.client.Dispatch('Lotus.NotesSession')
notesSession.Initialize(notesPass)

db_name = 'mail\iizs.nsf'
db = notesSession.getDatabase(notesServer, db_name)
view = db.GetView("($All)")
doc = view.getFirstDocument()
```

And I get the following error:

> (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'NotesSession', u'Notes
>   error: Wrong Password. (Passwords are case sensitive - be sure to use
>   correct upper and lower case.)'

Also tried leaving password blank and disabling 'request password for LN applications' in the interface. With a blank password, I am getting the following error message:

> (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'NotesDatabase', u'Database
>   AALMBX01/Server/...!!mail\iizs.nsf has not been opened yet'

I have tried the following:

1. Using [lnlib](https://github.com/zejn/lnlib) and get_session function.
2. Checking that notus.ini file is in place (C:\Users\iizs\NotesData in my case) and includes the reference to userid (tried adding the full path to userid file, which is located in C:\Users\iizs\NotesData\data).
3. Adding a value to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Lotus\Notes(optional-version)\NotesIniPath
4. Added the folder containing notes.ini file (C:\Users\iizs\NotesData) and user.id file (C:\Users\iizs\NotesData\data) to the PATH environment variable.

The error is still the same. Tried copying user.id to one of system folders too (system32) - did not help either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32com.client
import pywintypes
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from win32com.client import constants
notesSession = Dispatch('Lotus.NotesSession')
dir(constants)
dir(notesSession)
Password = 'S3cretP455w0rd'
Server = 'yourserver/yourapp' # yourserver = '' if local
scPath = 'view.nsf'
notesSession.Initialize(Password)
```

HTH!!

Also, one 'gotcha' that happened for me was network drives - if your NOTES.INI file contains a network path, try deleting and adding it in the Python code:

```
[code]
import os 
os.system('net use w: /delete') 
os.system('net use w: \\\\apps\\NotesFolder') 
[/code]
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Now I am getting an error message: "(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'NotesSession', u'Notes error: Wrong Password. (Passwords are case sensitive - be sure to use correct upper and lower case.)', None, 0, -2147217504), None)". I am certainly using the right passwords, could you please advise what could be the issue?

Comment: Also, when I try to leave the password blank, it connects fine but then I get an error on GetView() saying "Database ... has not been opened yet'. Any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't hit that error before, but make sure your Python script has your password in single quotes (eg 'password'), not double quotes (eg "password") as some languages try to 'interpret' the string. I'm pretty new to Python, so I'm not sure if that's true for this language, but it's been a roadblock in other places ...

Comment: Also, one 'gotcha' that happened for me was network drives - if your NOTES.INI file contains a network path, try deleting and adding it in the Python code (see edited answer above, can't add code here)

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing of the above helps. Changed the original thread to reflect the changes. Stuck.

Comment: Check that you don't have two *.id files on your system - it's possible that the wrong one is being accessed which is causing the issue. Drop into a command line and go to the root (cd \) then do a search for id files with the command "dir user.id /s" - this may take a while to run ... also refer to your NOTES.INI file to make sure it is pointing to the correct one ...